# Problems with authentication login in Pizza Shack WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm doing the tutorial for WSO2 API Manager, and I finally got to the part where I have to create an application in the DevPortal, get the token and change the `web.xml` file with the right credentials for the token that I got, to manage to log-in on PizzaShack site.

After that, when I try to log-in on the PizzaShack site, it returns me an error:

> `Authentication failed for user`

And when I go to the CMD log to see what is going on, this is what it returns to me everytime I try to log-in:

> `INFO - LogMediator STATUS = Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = /token, HEALTH CHECK URL = /token`

I don't know what to do to solve this error, I already tried a bunch of things and nothing works, If anyone can help me with this, I'm very thankful.

Comment: What's the APIM version? Will you be able to point to that tutorial here?

Comment: My version of de APIM is 4.0.0.
I'm brazilian, the tutorial is in portuguese, you still want me to point it? I dont know If anybody will understand the tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the login url as in https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/commit/f30d450b1cb13ff6296dc701995f40c06e427c2f

1. You can do the change as in the commit
2. Build the sample and get the war file
3. Then replace this war file in wso2am-4.0.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/ location

Comment: Hi, I've done the first step, but can you help me with the other steps? I dont think I know how to build the sample and get the war file. The war file that I got on the tutorial was just downloading from a link that the instructor gave to the students. He doesn't really explain how to get this file and why we need it.

Comment: Oh, actually, I think I could log-in now, but when the site redirects me to login.jsp, it gives me HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error.