# WSO2 API Manager - PizzaShack site giving HTTP 500 Internal Error after login

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

So yesterday I was having some issues with login authentication on the login page of the "Pizza Shack" application in WSO2 API Manager, and couldn't find answers anywhere, so I came here and asked, I got help and everything worked fine. Here's my question from yesterday issue so you can understand my actual problem a little better:

> [Problems with authentication login in Pizza Shack WSO2 API Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69457742/problems-with-authentication-login-in-pizza-shack-wso2-api-manager)

So, after I log-in on the PizzaShack site, it appears to me in the index.jsp page:

> HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

I'm actually a beginner in WSO2 API Manager so I dont really understand that much about what is causing this error and why. I tried searching for this error and found things that I dont understand very well, so, if anyone can help me, I appreciate it. Here's the error on CMD:`

> 

```
ERROR - [jsp] Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/pizzashack] threw exception [An exception occurred processing [index.jsp] at line [145]
142:             <ul class="thumbnails">
143:             <%
144:                    MenuItemManager manager = new MenuItemManager();
145:                    List<Pizza> menuItems = manager.getAvailablePizzaList(token);
146:                    String serverURL = PizzaShackWebConfiguration.getInstance().getServerURL();
147:                %>
148:             <%
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is produced due to the missing Pizzashack API WAR. I believe, that you have removed and replaced the existing `am#sample#pizzashack#v1.war` as instructed in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69457742/problems-with-authentication-login-in-pizza-shack-wso2-api-manager).

If yes, then you have to put back the removed `am#sample#pizzashack#v1.war` inside the `<apim>/repository/deployment/server/webapps` directory along with the newly built WAR artifact (which is `pizzashack.war`). If you have missed to take a backup of the existing `am#sample#pizzashack#v1.war`, try getting the same webapp from a fresh WSO2 API Manager 4.0.0 pack and deploy it. At the end, you will be having both the following WAR artifacts inside the `/webapps` directory of your pack

1. **am#sample#pizzashack#v1.war**: which is already in the 4.0.0 pack
2. **pizzashack.war**: which is built from the Product APIM Repo

Once after deploying the webapps as instructed, start the API Manager server, and navigate to and open `<apim>/repository/deployment/server/webapps/pizzashack/WEB-INF/web.xml` and make the following changes

- Update the `loginURL` as `http://localhost:9763/oauth2/token` if this has not been changed previously
- Update the `consumerKey` and `consumerSecret` with the correct Consumer credentials that you have generated from Devportal

Save the artifact, wait for a while to apply the changes.
Once applied successfully (you will see an INFO log in the carbon logs), you can try accessing the Pizza Shack Portal by going to the `http://localhost:9763/pizzashack`